# How does a decoder determines the size of Single NAL Unit in H264 decoding

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtp

As mentioned in RFC 6184 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#section-5.6 section 5.6 that Single NAL Unit packet can only contain one NAL unit.

My question is how does an decoder now at the receiving end identifies the size of this Single NAL unit or knows end of NAL unit in the Single NAL unit packet.

However in other packetization mode like STAP and others the size of a NAL unit is present as a part of the RTP payload.

Comment: If there's a single NAL/packet then its size is the size of the payload. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @aergistal I hope we both are on the same page related to the Single NAL unit packet format which is mentioned in RFC 6184. Now regarding my question , the thing which confuses me is the Single NAL unit is encapsulated in the the RTP packet once the RTP header is removed by the decoder the RTP payload has the Single NAL unit, now here first 8 bits are NAL unit header and the rest is the NAL unit data i.e. frame related information. How do we know that the frame related information is ended and till what point I should assume that there is NAL data, there can be RTP padding also.

Comment: The RTP padding presence and length is specified in the [RTP header](http://www.siptutorial.net/RTP/images/header.gif). When the P bit is set the last octet of the RTP padding is the count of bytes that should be ignored at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is how does an decoder now at the receiving end identifies the size of this Single NAL unit or knows end of NAL unit in the Single NAL unit packet.

The OS/socket API tells you what the size of a received UDP (RTP) packet is. In the case of TCP streaming, the size of the RTP packet is typically prepended to the RTP packet (both in [RTSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) and [RFC4571](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4571)).
After processing the [RTP header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550), the payload *is* the NAL unit in [single nal unit mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#section-5.6).

While a typical RTP header is 12 bytes, you should parse it according to [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) as the size depends on CSRCs and RTP header extensions.

In the case of STAP, you need to know the size as there are multiple NALUs in a single RTP packet. Hence you have to parse each one by reading the size.

Comment: Agreed that in case of STAP , MTAP and FU - A/B there are always ways of identifying the size of the NAL unit using length or start/end bits. Probably I will read up more on RTP in case of TCP and UDP. But before that couple of more doubts 1) you the size of RTP packet by payload size of UDP but after removing the RTP header from it what remains is the single NAL unit. Now this single NAL unit has 8 bit header and the rest is NAL data which might even contain RTP padding, now here how does a decoder determines the length till which it should consider the NAL data.

Comment: Also I would like to add that we are saying that in case of TCP as transport mechanism the size of the RTP packet is typically prepended to the RTP packet but how do I know that the RTP packet is not byte padded. Means there is NAL data along with byte padding in RTP payload in that case how do I know the end of the NAL unit.

Comment: Generally the NAL unit you get from an encoder is what you put as payload in SNU mode, similarly the RTP payload is what you feed back to the decoder. If you do have to pad, see the section on padding: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550#section-5.1

Comment: Ralf Thanks the comment with how padding is taken care by the decoder is helpful and clarifies how the decoder gets the NAL unit data from the Single NAL unit.